# Can't set default layout in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to select a layout for a new page in wordpress. I watched some YouTube tutorials and they had a menu showing the layouts that can be used. I have the following menu with no options.

[image]

I looked for the right option in the Theme Settings as written, but the only item i found is the following:

[image]

Is there any way to fix this? Is there any other way to achieve the same result?
Thank you for your time and consideration.

Edit:
List of my plugins:

- Yoast SEO
- WP Reset
- Simple Social Icons
- Simple Real Estate Pack
- Simple Lightbox
- SI Captcha Anti-Spam
- Ninja Forms
- Google Analytics for WordPress by MonsterInsights
- Genesis Title Toggle
- Genesis eNews Esteso
- Elementor
- Akismet Anti-Spam
- AgentPress Listings

Comment: This seems to be a theme-specific thing as -as far as I know at least- WordPress doesn't offer such feature. Try contacting the developer of your theme and ask them about this.

Comment: @cabrerahector I edited my question in order to give you the list of my plugins, maybe by this you can have more details

Comment: As @cabrerahector wrote, that's a THEME option - has nothing to do with plugins. Read the documentation for your theme...